# SortBy project finish date not working

Tags: scala, sorting, playframework-2.0, left-join, slick

I'm trying to run a query in scala using slickDB.
It will get distinct project ids sorted with respect to their finish date.
It is giving me error Value project_finish_date is not a member of (models.Projects.type, models.ProjectInfo.type).
I replaced project_finish_date with id and it doesn't give any error.
However it gives error when I try to sortBy project_finish_date.

```
def getIDsSortedByFinishDate()(implicit session: Session): List[String] = {
(for {
  (p, t) <- Projects leftJoin ProjectData on (_.id === _.project_id) 
    } yield (p,t)).sortBy{ _.project_finish_date }.map {_.id}.list.distinct
}
```

Data Types are:

project_finish_data: Option[Date]

id = Int

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: Give the error message. As Dan D says, it might be a simple typo but we can't tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are yielding as tuple then you should be using tuple as param in your sortBy and map as following:

```
def getIDsSortedByFinishDate()(implicit session: Session): List[String] = {
(for {
  (p, t) <- Projects leftJoin ProjectData on (_.id === _.project_id) 
    } yield (p,t)).sortBy{ case(p, t) => t.project_finish_date }.map { case(p, t) => p.id}.list.distinct
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you wrote `project_finish_date` in your question, but in your code block used `project_finish_data`.  Could that be the issue?

Comment: This is a sample code as I can't paste the whole function. You're right that there is a typo error in the code that I pasted here.
Error I'm getting is not because of typo error.